Why does TypeScript not simplify this intersection type?
In TypeScript, it is possible to use intersection types to “narrow down” the type of a different field:
type Post = {type: "post", body: string}
type User = {type: "user", name: string}
type Entity = Post | User

/* narrows the type 'Entity' to either 'Post' or 'User' */
type PostAgain = Entity & {type: "post"}
type UserAgain = Entity & {type: "user"}

const post: PostAgain = getPost()
const body = post.body /* now, the field 'body' is known to exist in the type */

But if I want to have a more complex type involved in this “narrowing”, I get unexpected results.
/* now, the 'type' field involves arrays */
type Post = {type: ["post"], body: string}
type User = {type: ["user"], name: string}
type Entity = Post | User

/* does not work as expected! */
type PostAgain = Entity & {type: ["post"]}
type UserAgain = Entity & {type: ["user"]}

const post: PostAgain = getPost()
const body = post.body /* error here: 'body' is not known to be a field in the type */

The issue seems to arise from the fact TypeScript does not “see” that the type Entity & {type: ["post"]} is the same as Post, even though (as far as I can see) there are no other possibilities for it.
I’ve tried out some combinations of readonly for the array types, but without much luck.
From a conversation in the comments, it seems like what I want is not currently possible. Is there any reason as to why? Is it unsound? Is it too computationally expensive to implement? Is it simply “not implemented yet”, even though it could theoretically be? Is it too complicated to implement?

TypeScript does the simplification only for discriminated union types. A union is counted as such only when it has a discriminator property, which must have a literal type. That tuple doesn't count.

Intersections are only reduced to never in certain circumstances; "post" and "user" are valid discriminant types, so the intersection is reduced as per ms/TS36696#. ["post"] is not a valid discriminant type (it's not a literal/unit type) so intersections don't get reduced. There are quite a few questions in there; which ones are primary?

Well, if it can’t be made to work in any way, the question then becomes “why doesn’t it work?” Is it unsound? Could this warranted behavior be added in the future?

Perhaps more specifically, it seems to me like a type with a field of type never should itself be simplified to never, though I imagine this might not be desirable, but I cannot see why.

I'd say the authoritative answer is primarily that it would be computationally infeasible to do so in general (although if there were a strong case for specific carve-outs like ms/TS#36696 that could always happen), as per the TS team dev lead comments at https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1326575516250329088 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57246#issuecomment-1921925531. (There's also this) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer elaborating. If not, what am I missing?

That seems like it would be a satisfactory answer. (Though a dissatisfying conclusion!) Probably the only thing I’d like further clarification on is whether the constraint “has a literal type” (in the second bullet in the PR you linked) was indeed established because it would be computationally expensive (or whether it was arbitrary to simplify work). The tweet you linked doesn’t address that specifically, because it covers a much more general case.

The general answer to "why doesn't TypeScript aggressively reduce intersections of mutually-exclusive types to never?" is "it would be computationally infeasible to do so". It might seem reasonable to expect that {a: X} & {a: Y} should be reduced to never if X & Y is reduced to never. But this scales very badly; if the incompatible type occurs at some deeply nested place, then we'd be asking the compiler to do a full structural type check on all intersection types before proceeding. And some types are recursive, so this becomes actually impossible in lots of cases.
For an authoritative answer, see this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#57246 by the TS team dev lead: "It's not practical for every possible non-inhabitable type to be simplified to never -- this requires a potentially unbounded amount of work. Because it can't be done, it's not an invariant you should be trying to take a dependency on.", or this tweet by the same author referred to in microsoft/TypeScript#50581. You can fairly easily write a type that spits out a never somewhere very deep in the object, and we just can't expect TypeScript to hunt for these.

Pragmatically speaking, there are also cases where TypeScript intentionally allows such impossible intersections to exist. The canonical one is branded primitives of the form string & {prop: number} or number & {xyz: 123}. Clearly those things will never exist at runtime, but TypeScript pretends they do to allow you to pretend that there's some distinguishing structure between otherwise identical types. Aggressively reducing things to never would end up breaking cases like this.
Indeed, you could write something yourself which actually does exist at runtime, and is well-typed according to the type system, which TypeScript doesn't aggressively reduce:
const x = {
  a: "hello",
  get b(): never { throw new Error("Don't look at this poperty!"); }
}
/* const x: {
    a: number;
    readonly b: never;
} */

Here the value x is of a type whose b property is correctly of type never. But x exists just fine, and if you don't try to read the b property you can use it as much as you want:
console.log(x.a.toUpperCase()) // "HELLO"

Only if you access b do you run into trouble:
console.log(x.b) // OH NOEZ

So should x have been reduced to never? It's not clear what the benefit of such a reduction would be.  Of course these weird never-getter things might not be idiomatic, so it's not clear that there's a huge benefit to prevent the reduction, but it's important to keep in mind situations where seemingly impossible types actually can exist, so we'd be making breaking changes to TypeScript if we implemented them.

So, if TypeScript doesn't do that reduction in general, then why does it do it when the property in conflict is a literal type suitable for being the discriminant property of a discriminated union?
Well, this behavior actually didn't happen before TypeScript 3.9 introduced intersection reduction by discriminant properties, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#36696.
That was implemented as a fix for microsoft/TypeScript#36736, which was complaining that we couldn't use intersections to extract members from discriminated unions. The language maintainers could have said "use Extract<T, U> instead" but they checked to see what would happen if this were implemented, and it turned out not to break anything important, so they kept it.
If you go back to earlier versions of TypeScript you'll see that even things like "x" & "y" weren't originally reduced to never. First they were left alone, then they were reduced to never when appearing in unions, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#18438, and then they were eventually reduced to never entirely as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#31838.
So it's possible that in some future version of TypeScript, your code will behave as you expected. But for that to be true, it would need to be established that

there's community demand for such reduction
it can be done without too much extra compile time (so it would have to be a shallow analysis)
it doesn't break real world code that somehow depends on the intersection not being reduced

That seems unlikely, especially because ["x"] isn't really widely used as the sort of thing to discriminate on, but anything's possible!
Playground link to code

Thank you! Also, thank you for your mention of Extract<...>, which was enough for my specific use case.
